# 301 redirection remove parameters

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect this url :

```
http://loremipsum.com/en/videos?tmpl=component&print=1&page=
```

to

```
http://loremipsum.com/videos/all-videos/
```

So I write this 301 redirection :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^tmpl=component&print=1&page=$
RewriteRule ^en/videos$ /videos/all-videos/ [L,R=301]
```

It's redirect but , the url keeps all parameters :

```
http://loremipsum.com/videos/all-videos/?tmpl=component&print=1&page=
```

What I want is to remove these parameters.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: When will people finally start to read the documentation of the tools they use?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Apache ver 2.4 or later then you can use `QSD` to discard original query string:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^tmpl=component&print=1&page=$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^en/videos/?$ /videos/toutes-les-videos/ [L,NC,R=301,QSD]
```

On older Apache versions, you can a trailing `?` in the target for the same effect:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^tmpl=component&print=1&page=$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^en/videos/?$ /videos/toutes-les-videos/? [L,NC,R=301]
```